# How do I use application settings to store MySQL database connection info?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an in-house application and have always hardcoded the database connection string.  However, this time I want to do something different and give the users the ability to enter the information from the application.

I figured out that I can store the variables in the Application Settings and call them from code, but I can't figure out how to call them within the connection string.

Here's the code:

```
Dim dbConn As New MySqlConnection
dbConn.ConnectionString = "Server=172.43.96.271;Port=3306;Uid=someone;
Password=theirpassword;Database=thedb"
```

Hope I explained myself well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply concatenate the string together, or better yet, use the `String.Format` method:

```
dbConn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Password={3};Database={4}", My.Settings.Server, My.Settings.Port, My.Settings.Uid, My.Settings.Database)
```

If you were using MS SQL, I'd recommend using the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to do it, but since you're using MySql, it doesn't really apply.  You may be able to use it anyway, though.

Comment: SteveDog, thanks for your assistance.  I followed your advice and it seems to be working except that I'm getting a "Property is Read-Only" error when I try to set the textbox.text value back to the variable in the.  Here's the code I'm using:  'My.Settings.DB_Server = TextBoxDBServerIP.Text'

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use User Settings for this. 
And, if you want the users to input the separate parts of the connection string (Server, Post, Username, Password and DB), you would have to create a settings entry for each of those, and then construct the connection string from those values.

Here's a good article for this: [User Settings Applied](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25829/User-Settings-Applied)